# Precision and recall of 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification

I am working on a problem using DNN. There are 2 input variables (both categorical) and 1 target variable (binary). The accuracy on test data is 99.95%. I have done cross-validation (10 fold) and the accuracy is 99.96 (+- 0.05).

In my results, I see both precision and recall of 1.0. I have attached image of the confusion matrix and classification report here.

Q1. **Is this behavior ok?**

Q2. when I run the same model again with same parameters I **get different confusion matrix** every time however the accuracy is always near 99.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is your question. If your program is correct, the results should be correct. Your confusion matrices are not absolutely perfect, but they are close enough that the metrics become one when printed with two-digit precision. It is normal that the results very with every run, since, unless you fix the random seed, the weight initialization and training order will generally be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you do *not* have a pure 1.00 [precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall); that's merely the *reported* figure, which is rounded to two decimal places.  As you've already stated, your test accuracy and cross-validation accuracy are both well over 99.5%, the threshold for rounding to 1.00.  You will get this any time your experimental error rate is below one part in 2000.

This begs the question of whether it's reasonable for a trained model to have such high accuracy: yes, it is.  The potential accuracy depends upon the information separability in the data set: is it even *possible* to extract a separable space for the given data?  So far as the output is a (deterministic) function of the inputs, your model can achieve 100% accuracy.  You simply have a data set in which that is (nearly) possible.

Is that clear?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But what about the varying confusion matrix. The confusion matrices change everytime I run the model, sometime the number of FN are high and sometimes the FT are high. is this because I reshuffle the dataset everytime before running the model?

Comment: Yes, the numbers change because you're using different data.  Merely presenting the same observations in a different order will alter the training.  Different model initialization will alter the training.